# Cuda: Global memory broadcast to registers on Compute 5.0 architecture

Tags: memory, cuda

I have the following code:

```
__global__ void someKernel(unsigned char * global_mem, unsigned int * start) {
    unsigned int size;
    size = *(unsigned int *)&global_mem[start[blockIdx.x]];
    //Do many things with size
}
```

Where all of my threads from the same block will read the same memory location from the global memory and do many things with it.
How fast/slow is the copy going to be? I have a block of 256 threads.

Will the global memory broadcast to the whole block, or to a single warp (meaning I will have to do 256/32 reads from global memory)?

Would the following situation be better where I first read from global memory to shared memory and then I copy to a register (bearing the warp divergence and the synchronization overhead):

```
__global__ void someKernel(unsigned char * global_mem, unsigned int * start) {
    __shared__ int tmpsize;
    unsigned int size;
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    if (i == 0) {
        tmpsize = *(unsigned int *)&global_mem[start[blockIdx.x]];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    size = tmpsize;
    //Do many things with size
}
```

Would this be faster, considering that I have a huge grid with blocks of **256** threads and each block reads a different start location

Comment: why not benchmark the difference?  broadcast only works at the warp level, but once the data is fetched it should be in the cache for subsequent warps - resulting in near register speed.  If your grid is small enough (less than 16K blocks) then `start` might be a good candidate to put in `__constant__` memory.  Alternatively, proper decoration of your kernel parameters with `const __restrict__` might give some perf improvement as well.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the effects on cache. My grid is more like several million blocks..